# Windows Server 2012 Essentials shows wrong used space on SSD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, windows-server-2012

I am runnin a Windows Server 2012 Essentials and have a 100 GB System Partition from an 128GB SSD drive. Yesterday I got a warning from the system, that the space on this drive is out, so I checked, and Windows seems to report it wrong:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this or find out, what is actually taking the space? Check-Disk did not help, but shows the same "usage"...

Here is the Check-Disk log:

> Chkdsk was executed in scan mode on a volume snapshot.
>
> Checking file system on C: Volume label is System.
>
> Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
>
> Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
>
> Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
>
> Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further
>   action is required.
>
> ---
>
> CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...   File verification
>   completed.
>
> CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...   Multiple object id
>   files found.  Ignoring extra object id files.   Multiple quota files
>   found.  Ignoring extra quota files.   Multiple reparse file found. 
>   Ignoring extra reparse files.   Multiple Usn Journal file found. 
>   Ignoring extra Usn Journal files.   Index verification completed.
>
> CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...   Security
>   descriptor verification completed.   CHKDSK is verifying Usn
>   Journal...   Usn Journal verification completed.
>
> Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.   No
>   further action is required.
>
> 104867839 KB total disk space.
>    100434108 KB in 93859 files.
>       160264 KB in 29185 indexes.
>            0 KB in bad sectors.
>       784315 KB in use by the system.
>        65536 KB occupied by the log file.
>      3489152 KB available on disk.
>
> 4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
>     26216959 total allocation units on disk.
>       872288 allocation units available on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'd trust Chkdsk and Windows. I wouldn't trust Tree Size.

The pie chart, in particular, is about very accurate.  This is taken straight from the file system's metadata files.

Tree Size traverses folders and adds up files. Which is inherently broken because it does not properly add up hardlinks and files it cannot access.

Comment: Actually TreeSize was right - please se my own answer...

Answer (score 0):

I must have totally forgotten, that even if it is a Server it is still Windows...

Rebooted and saw this:
[image]

"Funny thing" (and actually the reason I rebooted) was, that the free space was getting smaller by ~1GB/h!

Comment: Sounds like you don't have TRIM support enabled.

Comment: How can I check/change that?

Comment: The following article will get you started http://lifehacker.com/5640971/check-if-trim-is-enabled-for-your-solid-state-drive-in-windows-7 more research should be done of course.

Comment: TRIM or no TRIM, for file system used vs free this does not matter. File system looks at free vs. available clusters.